# Symfony2 Conditional Validation

Tags: symfony

I have a FormType method.

```
<?php
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('paymentMethod', 'choice', array(
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => array(
                    'cach' => 'Cach',
                    'check'=> 'Check'
                )
            ))
            ->add('checkId', 'integer', array(
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('submit', 'submit');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Post',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_post';
    }
}
?>
```

The field **checkId** is displaying only when the choice '**check**' is selected with the field **paymentMethod**.

Here is the javascript:

```
PaymentMethod = {
    hideCheckId: function(){
        $('.check-id').hide();
    },

    showCheckId: function(){
        $('.check-id').fadeIn();
    },

    whenPaymentMethodChange: function(){
        $('#appbundle_post_paymentMethod').on('change', function(){
            var method = this.value ;

            if(method == 'check'){
                PaymentMethod.showCheckId();
            }else{
                PaymentMethod.hideCheckId();
            }
        })
    }
};
PaymentMethod.hideCheckId();
PaymentMethod.whenPaymentMethodChange();
```

I would like the field 'checkId' to be required to TRUE only when the option check is selected.
How can I do that?

Comment: use a callback (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) or expression (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks, Here is the solution for everyone:

Add a callback method function in your entity class.

```
    /**
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     * @Assert\Callback()
     */
    public function isPaymentIsCheck(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->getPaymentMethod() == 'check' and $this->getCheckId() == '') {
            $context->buildViolation('A check ID as to be defined')
                ->atPath('checkID')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add the **Assert** and **ExecutionContextInterface** component in you entity class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;    
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
```

And finally don't forget to display errors in the twig template:

```
    {% if form.vars.errors|length %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ form_errors(form) }}</div>
    {% endif %}
```

Hope it will help you.

More info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Answer (score 0):

What KevinR wrote would definitely solve your problem, but in my opinion there's even cleaner solution:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#group-sequence-providers

> Imagine a User entity which can be a normal
>   user or a premium user. When it's a premium user, some extra
>   constraints should be added to the user entity (e.g. the credit card
>   details). To dynamically determine which groups should be activated,
>   you can create a Group Sequence Provider. First, create the entity and
>   a new constraint group called Premium:

This is exactly your how you would solve this kinda of problem

```
public function getGroupSequence()
{
    $groups = array('Post'); //Or array('Default') whichever you prefer

    if ($this->getPaymentMethod() === 'Check') {
        $groups[] = 'Check';
    }

    return $groups;
}
```

Of course you'll have to add validation group paymentMethod property in your entity mapping. Here's annotation example, for more examples check above link.

```
/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(groups={"Check"})
 */
private $checkId;
```